# Extracting data from XML not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, xml

I am a beginner in XML and JSON and I cannot display my data in my HTML.  I am trying to extract the data from the xml api and display it in my div.

But nothing seems to show up in my div. Sorry if my code is a bit messy. You can refer to http://api.nea.gov.sg/api/WebAPI/?dataset=24hrs_forecast&keyref=781CF461BB6606AD48001FDD2657FAF0F8C6C64F041BB440 if you want to see how the XML file looks like.

UPDATE
I can now display my data after changing the data source to a json one by i can only display 2 line of data and i have no idea why is it so.

```
    var json4day; //global variables - all functions can read and store values inside

$(function() {
    Load4day(); //call function to load data****
});

function Load4day(){
    //2 hour code here
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/4-day-weather-forecast",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {"api-key": "nVjYBrTc4KMLNjJQrKwlc0Be9V5zFYXZ" 
                }
    })
    .done(function(json) { //tween max oncomplete
        json4day=json;
        ShowData(); //load PSI*****
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
}



function ShowData(){
    console.log("Show data");
    console.log(json4day);
    var tforecasts=json4day.items[0].forecasts.length;
    console.log(tforecasts);
    for(var i=0;i<tforecasts;i++){
        var fc=json4day.items[0].forecasts[i].forecast;
        var date=json4day.items[0].forecasts[i].date;
        var icon=json4day.items[0].forecasts[i].relative_humidity;
    //  console.log(lt);
        var html="<div data-index='"+i+"'>"+date+"<br>"+fc+"<br></div>";
        var html2="<div data-index='"+i+"'>"+date+"<br>"+fc+"<br></div>";

        $(".content1").append(html);
        $(".content1").html(html);
        $(".content1").append(html2);
        $(".content1").html(html2);

    }



}
```

I am trying to display my data in the div below

```
div id="main1">
    <div class="b1">


        <div class="4hr">

            <p class="t1">4 Hour Forecast </p>


            <div id="target">
            click here




            </div>

        </div>



        <!--<iframe width="600" height="400" src="https://data.gov.sg/dataset/weather-forecast/resource/4df6d890-f23e-47f0-add1-fd6d580447d1/view/91f4e399-5a83-4cab-9491-09464db88661" frameBorder="0"> </iframe>-->

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>The problem here is definitely, you working with the wrong object in mind.</del>

<del>You don't have a JSON object as return from your ajax call. Instead you have now a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object which behavior is diffrent from a JSON.</del>

**After Update:**

Your code replaces the content:

```
$(".content1").append(html);
// $(".content1").html(html); // Replaces the 'content' in 'content1' class 
// $(".content1").append(html2); // Appends the same 'content' again
// $(".content1").html(html2); // Replaces the 'content' in 'content1' class
```

If your remove the last 3 lines it will work fine.

There is a huge diffrent between [`JQuery.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) (which replaces the content in given element) and [`JQuery.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) (which appends the content at the end of the given element).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var json4day; //global variables - all functions can read and store values inside

        $(function () {
            $(".content1").html("");
            Load4day(); //call function to load data****
        });

        function Load4day() {
            //2 hour code here
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/4-day-weather-forecast",
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    "api-key": "nVjYBrTc4KMLNjJQrKwlc0Be9V5zFYXZ"
                }
            })
                .done(function (json) { //tween max oncomplete
                    json4day = json;
                    ShowData(); //load PSI*****
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    console.log("error");
                });
        }

        function ShowData() {
            console.log("Show data");
            console.log(json4day);
            var tforecasts = json4day.items[0].forecasts.length;
            console.log(tforecasts);
            for (var i = 0; i < tforecasts; i++) {
                var fc = json4day.items[0].forecasts[i].forecast;
                var date = json4day.items[0].forecasts[i].date;
                var icon = json4day.items[0].forecasts[i].relative_humidity;
                //  console.log(lt);
                var html = "<div data-index='" + i + "'>" + date + "<br>" + fc + "<br></div>";
                var html2 = "<div data-index='" + i + "'>" + date + "<br>" + fc + "<br></div>";
                $(".content1").append(html);
                //$(".content1").html(html);
                //$(".content1").append(html2);
                //$(".content1").html(html2);    
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main1">
        <div class="b1">
            <div class="4hr">
                <p class="t1">4 Hour Forecast </p>
                <div id="target">
                    click here
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="content1">some text</div>

            <!--<iframe width="600" height="400" src="https://data.gov.sg/dataset/weather-forecast/resource/4df6d890-f23e-47f0-add1-fd6d580447d1/view/91f4e399-5a83-4cab-9491-09464db88661" frameBorder="0"> </iframe>-->
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hihi, thanks for the reply. I have edited my post and have changed my data source to json. My data now displays! but it only shows the forecast for 1 day. How can i make it to show for more days?